# Conteúdo na mesma linha quando puxo do mysqli

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Eu hospedo no meu banco de dados um campo de text, com minhas espaço entre parágrafos. Porem quando eu puxo ele para inserir sem ser em campo textarea ele vem todo em uma linha somente, sem espaçamento.

**Objetivo:**

```
Bom dia Bruno
Agradecemos pelo seu contato!

Segue em anexo orçamento para 140 camisetas modelo tradicional em tecido 100% poliamida UNI. Estampa em até 4 cores, 2 cores peito, 2 cores costas, centralizadas..

Frete por conta do cliente através da transportadora JAMEF.

Prazo de produção 30 dias a partir da confirmação do pedido.

Forma de pagamento: parcelado no cartão em 3x ou 50% na confirmação do pedido e o pagamento do saldo restante na data de envio para liberação do pedido.

Para fechamento do pedido precisamos que todas as logos sejam enviadas vetorizadas corel, AI, Eps ou pdf editÃ¡vel.

Permaneço a disposição.

Atenciosamente,

Marcelo de Souza.
```

**O que acontece:**

```
Bom dia Bruno Agradecemos pelo seu contato! Segue em anexo orçamento para 140 camisetas modelo tradicional em tecido 100% poliamida UNI. Estampa em até 4 cores, 2 cores peito, 2 cores costas, centralizadas.. Frete por conta do cliente através da transportadora JAMEF. Prazo de produção 30 dias a partir da confirmação do pedido. Forma de pagamento: parcelado no cartão em 3x ou 50% na confirmação do pedido e o pagamento do saldo restante na data de envio para liberação do pedido. Para fechamento do pedido precisamos que todas as logos sejam enviadas vetorizadas corel, AI, Eps ou pdf editÃ¡vel. Permaneço a disposição. Atenciosamente, Marcelo de Souza.
```

Comment: Como está exibindo o resultado, no HTML? Lembre-se que a quebra de linha padrão, `\n`, não funciona no HTML. É necessário utilizar a função `nl2br` do PHP para alterá-los para `<br>`.

Comment: Quando fui ver o código fonte do html da pagina saiu normal, porem na exibição não

Comment: @LucasMartins se a resposta estiver certa, assinale-a como tal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exemplo:**

```
$frase = "Bom dia Bruno Agradecemos pelo seu contato! \nSegue em anexo orçamento para 140 camisetas modelo tradicional em tecido 100% poliamida UNI. Estampa em até 4 cores, 2 cores peito, 2 cores costas, centralizadas.. \nFrete por conta do cliente através da transportadora JAMEF. \n";

echo nl2br($frase);
```

**Saída:**

```
Bom dia Bruno Agradecemos pelo seu contato! 
Segue em anexo orçamento para 140 camisetas modelo tradicional em tecido 100% poliamida UNI. Estampa em até 4 cores, 2 cores peito, 2 cores costas, centralizadas.. 
Frete por conta do cliente através da transportadora JAMEF.
```

**Saída em HTML:**

```
Bom dia Bruno Agradecemos pelo seu contato! <br />Segue em anexo orçamento para 140 camisetas modelo tradicional em tecido 100% poliamida UNI. Estampa em até 4 cores, 2 cores peito, 2 cores costas, centralizadas.. <br />Frete por conta do cliente através da transportadora JAMEF.<br />
```